# Package Version not updating under VSTS Build and .NET Standard

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines, .net-standard, gitversion

I'm building a .NET Standard component using VSTS-Build and GitVersion. And because its .NET Standard I'm having to use `msbuild /t:pack` instead of the nuget pack step.

This has resulted in the package version number always being 1.0.0 which I assume means that "PackageVersion" isn't being set. The GitVersion documentation says:

> the following MSBuild properties are set when UpdateVersionProperties is true

but there doesn't appear to be an option for that.

Anyone know how to get this to work?

Project file:

[image]

I changed 2 things from a working build definition, I disabled the Nuget Pack step and I added "/t:pack" as an msbuild argument in the Visual Studio Build step.

Nuspec file.

[image]

Comment: `PackageVersion` is defaulted to `Version`, which GitVersion sets. please share more details of your setup (csproj file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the [GitVersion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion) task ahead of MSBuild task. And it will generate nuget package version with 1.1.0. But it won't update the new version (1.1.0) in your source code, so when you build once again, you will always get the nuget package version 1.1.0.

And there has **another way to generate nuget packages and specify package version** as you need. Detail build definition as below:

- .NET Core task with command `restore`: specify the path to  .csproj.
- .NET Core task with command `build`: specify the path to .csproj.
- .NET Core task with command `pack`: specify the path to .csproj and the package version (`/p:PackageVersion`)  as you need.

[image]

**To use Gitversion variables for nuget package**, you just need to add the argument `/p:PackageVersion=$(GitVersion.Major).$(GitVersion.Minor).$(GitVersion.Patch)` in .NET Core pack task.

[image]

The variables `$(GitVersion.Major)`, `$(GitVersion.Minor)` and `$(GitVersion.Patch)` are auto generated after executing GitVersion task.

Comment: And I assume I would replace the version number by the environment variable created by GitVersion?

Comment: Environment variables can be used in `/p:PackageVersion`, but you should notice the format should be `major.minor.patch`.

Comment: So would you be able to clarify in your example how I make use of GitVersion to generate the package version? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I added the setting to use GitVersion for package in the end of my answer, and you can have a try.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you - I will give this a try when I am back in the office on Monday.

Comment: Quick follow on, do you know how to get "dotnet nuget push" to work? I've set that as my last step but get "No executable found matching command "dotnet-nuget push""

Comment: You can try with **NuGet push** task instead.

Comment: Thanks yes - I already have that working - I was just trying for a *clean* dotnet based build :)